# Docker-compose logs command can't show symbol characters, but docker logs command can?

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, encoding

Can someone explain to me, why

1. "docker-compose logs" can't show/parse symbol characters,
2. but "docker logs" showing symbol characters?

And is there any way to fix "docker-compose logs"?

1. [docker-compose logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iue3.png)
2. [docker logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqFVz.png)

My environment:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 (x86_64)

Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57

docker-compose version 1.28.4, build cabd5cfb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by updating the docker-compose version from v1.29.2 to v2.2.3.

But strangely, on the docker-compose official installation page, they are using the v1.29.2 version to install. I don't know why, but may be backward compatibility issues...
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install

Although I found docker-compose new releases from the official Github repo:
https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

And I installed a new version from their GitHub repo releases.